# How to construct dependencies when packaging a python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I am building a python package to push to PyPI and am having a lot of trouble specifying the correct dependencies in my setup.py. As I see it my, options are:

1. Version agnostic e.g.

```
    install_requires=[
        'packageA',
        'packageB',
    ]
```

this approach gives maximum flexibility although if either package1 or package2 release a new breaking change, my package can/will break.

2. Versions pinned e.g.

```
    install_requires=[
       'packageA==1.2.3',
       'packageB==4.5.6',
    ]
```

this approach gives maximum reliability, but is far too restricting on users as if they want to install my package along with other packages which are dependent on packageA or packageB, they are very likely to get dependency conflicts.

3. Specify a range of versions e.g.

```
    install_requires=[
       'packageA>=1.2,<2',
       'packageB>=4.5,<6',
    ]
```

This seems like the optimal approach, but there is a lot of work involved in determining which specific versions of each dependency my package is compatible with. I was hoping I could trust other package maintainers to follow semantic versioning of their releases, however I've already seen cases where "minor" and "patch" version increases have broken my package functionality. It seems very unrealistic to test my package with all possible combinations of versions of my dependencies.

Are there any better solutions for this? I find it hard to believe this problem hasn't been solved already by open source community, given how ubiquitous it would seem to be.

Comment: You could use pin to major and minor versions using `~=` such as `packageA~=1.2.3`. In my experience this leaves enough freedom for pip to resolve dependencies from multiple packages (not always though).

Comment: How about specifying `>=` version only by default, and adding `<` version when you become aware that newer version breaks compatibility?